# How to align five equations on three lines, e.g., 2-2-1, with the last equation centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to use the alignat environment to arrange five equations on three lines as follows: two equations on the first line, two equations  on the second line (aligned with those of the first line), and the fifth equation **centered** on the third line by itself. For what is worth, here's my failed attempt:

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
a ={}& b 
&\qquad &
c ={}& d 
\\
e ={}&f 
&\qquad &
g ={}& h
\\
{\centering
 i = j
 }
\end{alignat}
```

Please note I don't want the equation `i=j` on the third row to be aligned to the left, nor to the right, nor aligned with any particular piece of the other four equations, I really want it by itself on the third row, and centered on that row. I can produce the first two lines with no problem (using either align or alignat), but I can't get the single equation on the third line to be centered!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I removed 'thanks' from your post since we omit this. Instead, you should [up-vote and accept the answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask), giving the answerer the site reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need each line to be numbered, then you can nest `alignat` inside `gather`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignat}{2}
a &= b &\qquad
c &= d
\\
e &=f &
g &= h
\end{alignat}
\\
 i = j
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Without numbers, here's the way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
a &= b &\qquad
c &= d
\\
e &=f &
g &= h
\end{alignedat}
\\
 i = j
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, something like this? And remark: `&` should be before `=`, not after it. This will as well automatically use the correct spacing.

```
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
  a &= b
&
  c &= d 
\\
  e &= f 
&
  g &= h
\end{aligned}
\\
  i = j
\end{gather*}
```

Answer (score 4):

A regular `array` would work, given that you provide some help in terms of spacing between the columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r@{{}={}}l@{\qquad}r@{{}={}}l}
    f(x) & ax^2 + bx + c & g(x) & mx + c \\[\jot]
    f_1(x) & 2x^2 + 3x - 4 & g_1(x) & 3x - 1 \\[\jot]
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{h(x)=ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The column specification `@{{}={}}` handles the equal signs between functions f and g, and separates them by `\qquad`, while `\\[\jot]` adds a little vertical space between the equations. The last equation is centred in the traditional way using `\multicolumn{.}{c}{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

Not perhaps relevant here, but this is how I would do it with plain TeX (I used Werner's example content):

```
$$
  \displaylines{
    \eqalign{f(x)&=ax^2+bx+c\cr f_1(x)&=2x^2+3x-4}
    \qquad
    \eqalign{g(x)&=mx+c\cr g_1(x)&=3x-1}
    \cr\noalign{\kern\dp\strutbox}
    h(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
  }
$$
\bye
```

[image]